$L^2$-estimate for solution of elliptic PDE with inhomogeneous Dirichlet data
While reading some lecture notes (to be precise, Alouge's notes for Introduction to periodic homogenization, Proof of Corollary 6.1), I came across an estimate of the following form:
Let $\Omega\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ be a sufficiently nice domain, $A\in C^\infty(\overline{\Omega};\mathbb{R}^{2\times 2})$ a smooth, elliptic coefficients and $g\in H^1(\Omega)$ a given function. Now we consider the solution $u$ to the following PDE with inhomogeneous boundary data:
$$
-\text{div}(A\nabla u)=0\: \text{in }\Omega,\\
u_{|\partial\Omega}=g.
$$
Now the author claims the following estimate:
$$
\lVert u \rVert_{L^2(\Omega)}\leq C\lVert g\rVert_{L^2(\partial\Omega)}.
$$
I only know the easy estimate $\lVert u \rVert_{H^1(\Omega)}\leq C\lVert g\rVert_{H^1(\Omega)}$ (by rewriting the PDE as an equation with homogeneous boundary data for $v:=u-g$). However, in the application I am interested in, the gradient of $g$ has bad behaviour ($g$ oscillates), so I want to avoid this term.
In anyone familiar with this estimate (or a similar one) and can either provide me a reference or a sketch of a proof?

After some hours of digging through research, I found a source for the estimate I was looking for and will post it in case someone happens to stumble across this estimate too:
Theorem 3 in "Homogenization of Elliptic Problems with $L^p$ Boundary Data" (by Marco Avellaneda and Fang-Hua Lin, 1987).
The proof sadly seems be not that easy and relies on estimates for Green's functions and Poisson kernels for elliptic operators.
